# Exsol package didn't work with me

Tags: exercises, exsol

Exsol package didn't work with me in this code:

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{exsol}

\begin{document}

        \begin{exercises}[columns=2]
        \begin{exercise}
            Calculate $y = 5 + 7$
        \end{exercises}
        \begin{solution}
            $y = 12$
        \end{solution}
        \begin{exercise}
            Calculate $y = 7 - 12$
        \end{exercises}
        \begin{solution}
            $y = -5$
        \end{solution}
    \end{exercises}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `exsol` package requires Babel (although the manual says it is optional). You can use any language that you want, for example `english`.

Furthermore, in your code, you close a single exercise with `\end{exercises}`, which should not have the `s` at the end (only the full block should end with `\end{exercises}`).

Working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{exsol}

\begin{document}

        \begin{exercises}[columns=2]
        \begin{exercise}
            Calculate $y = 5 + 7$
        \end{exercise}
        \begin{solution}
            $y = 12$
        \end{solution}
        \begin{exercise}
            Calculate $y = 7 - 12$
        \end{exercise}
        \begin{solution}
            $y = -5$
        \end{solution}
    \end{exercises}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry....I have not the possibility to vote this answer. I have deleted my answer.

Comment: But do you know why isn't there enough supporting for this package or questions ?

Comment: @MamounRagab the `exsol` package is not very well-known and not very widely used I think, therefore there are not many questions about it. The reason for that is that other packages for exercises are very popular, such as `xsim` and `probsoln`.

Comment: @Marijn https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/561664/193664

Comment: @MamounRagab  (A) Likely (package-using community-size)*(question-raising coefficient) < ε. Why? Hypothesis: the usage volume and the question rate are  proportional to the size of the manual. `ExSol` doc is very tiny. Hypothesis2: the use-case is too niche or too general. H3: *adhoc* independent coding to achieve equivalent result is too easy. H4: Has the need peaked? (B) You may become the expert on the package; then, you may promote it as an alternative answer. (C) It seems to be a subset of `fancyvrb` package. (D) I can see a use-case for it for linguistic/language/translation matters.

Comment: Now I can vote :-) you. Very good.